# OpenCV - Draw only objects that keypoints refer to using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm able to detect keypoints and descriptors

```
keypoints, des = surf.detectAndCompute(gray_image,None)
```

I'm able to draw keypoints

```
output_image = cv2.drawKeypoints(output_image, keypoints)
```

I'm able to locate keypoints from the image below that only correspond to text perfectly. I want to them copy the text onto a new image.

How can I draw only the objects the `keypoints` refer to?

[source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0DQs.png)

Here is the output of the keypoints
[keypoints only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5xf9.png)

Ultimately i want the keypoints only image to have the text instead of the keypoint markers

Comment: For that you may need to identify the object in the context as well. Then if the `keypoint` is within the detected object, you can highlight that particular object

Comment: How do you identify the object in the context?

Comment: Can you upload a sample image you are working with

Comment: is your question about segmentation of the object from the rest of image? , or just get the focus on the part where the key-points are..

Comment: I'm able to extract keypoints referring to text. I just want to be able to create a new image consisting only of text as matched by the keypoints.

Comment: hint: if ur app is simple try to get a 'rect' around every keypoint (for a threshold distance ) and show 'em only ,if you want more perfection, you can use k-means clustring and then show every rect of every group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do have a look at this approach. It is not so tidy but you can possibly refine it to suit your needs.

I obtained keypoints on the given image using `cv2.ORB_create()`, for which I obtained this:

```
img = cv2.imread(filename,0)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp = orb.detect(img,None)
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,None,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
cv2.imshow('keypoint_on_text.jpg', img2)
```

[image]

You can use `surf` for better detection of keypoints.

Then I obtained an image having a solid color(black in this case) having the same shape as that of the image. I drew these obtained keypoints on this black image.

```
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
mask[:] = (0, 0, 0) 

fmask = cv2.drawKeypoints(mask,kp,None,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
cv2.imshow('fmask.jpg', fmask)
```

[image]

Now I converted this to grayscale image and applied threshold to binarize it. I then found contours on this image and drew them with a bigger radius.

```
graymask = cv2.cvtColor(fmask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, th = cv2.threshold(graymask, 50, 255, 0)
_, contours , _= cv2.findContours(th,2,1)
rep = cv2.drawContours(fmask, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 5)
cv2.imshow('contours.jpg',rep)
```

[image]

I converted this to greyscale, binarized it and masked it with the original image to finally obtain this:

```
repmask = cv2.cvtColor(rep,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(repmask, 50, 255, 0)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = th1)
cv2.imshow('Only_Text.jpg',res)
```

[image]

As you can see, certain portions of the desired text is visible. If you use `surf` detection, you will be able to obtain more portion of text.

Comment: If you require help with coding,  do reach out. I hope this helps. There may be better ways out there. But this is what struck me first. :D

Comment: Can you provide how you did: "I converted this to greyscale, binarized it and masked it with the original image to finally obtain this"?

Comment: Check the solution again. I have added relevant code.

Comment: `graymask = cv2.cvtColor(fmask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, th = cv2.threshold(graymask, 50, 255, 0)
_, contours , _= cv2.findContours(th,2,1)
` isn't finding any contours, i'm using 2.4 so my syntax is contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(th,2,1) but still no luck

Comment: the error I get:    repmask = cv2.cvtColor(rep, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv-20170215-44295-5rgz56/opencv-2.4.13.2/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Comment: so is contours only the problem?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is just backwards incompat changes from 2->3

Comment: Glad you managed to figure it out. Come up with a way to enhance this and let me know :D